# File upload PHP work fine from my machine but for others and mobile upload seems to not work its a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

THis works fine locally and on my computer from my browser but on other devices and mobile seems to not work what could be the issue. I have tried a few methods and looked up but I cant seem to find anything that explains it

```
$email = $_POST['email2'];
$phone = $_POST['phone2'];

      
if (($_FILES['my_file']['name']!="")){
  // Where the file is going to be stored

      $target_dir = "wp-content/sdfjsfsdfewgjksdhfsdkfds/". "" . $email . "" . $phone;
      $file = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
      $path = pathinfo($file);
      $filename = $path['filename'];
      $ext = $path['extension'];
      $temp_name = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
      $path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.".".$ext;
      $file_size = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
      $maxsize = 104857600;

    $allowed = array("application/x-zip-compressed", "application/octet-stream");

   
  // Check if file already exists
  if (file_exists($path_filename_ext)) {

   }else if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {

    }else if ($file_size > $maxsize || $file_size == 0){      
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(".over-error").removeClass("hide");
        $(".tooLarge-yes").addClass("hide");
        $(".tooLarge-no").removeClass("hide");
        
        
        </script>'; 
    }else{
   move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
   }
  }
```

Comment: make sure that the upload folder is writable (so that people can upload files)

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work. I see a lot of `if` statements that are empty, and I'm hoping that you just redacted them for here but they are set to scream loudly. Also, `move_uploaded_file` will return `false` on failure and give a WARNING, please check both

Comment: @KenLee Yes the folder is set writable for all users on the server

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes I havent added any messages but they prevent from for example not to upload files that are not the type, I will try to see maybe its a cache problem and it hasn't changed the folder that they are saved to